# What is a quadravariate distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

**Question:** What is a quadravariate distribution?

**Motivation:** I found a reference to quadravariate distributions in [Priestley (1981) *Spectral Analysis and Time Series*](http://books.google.com.au/books/about/Spectral_analysis_and_time_series.html?id=olYZAQAAIAAJ) on p325, but no definition (the author seems to think it is common knowledge). 10 minutes of googling revealed that the term gets used in quite a few papers, but I am still unable to find a definition anywhere.

Comment: I'd interpret it to be a distribution on 4 variables - the next in the series *univariate, bivariate, trivariate, ...*. However, it's more often spelled *quadrivariate*, which might explain why you had trouble finding it. Googling *quadrivariate* turns up many hits. But for that matter, when I google *quadravariate* the second and fourth hits (that I get, your experience may be different) are consistent with this interpretation, so it's not hard to find. What's the name of the Priestly reference?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for the response. If you turn that into an answer I'll give you the tick. Re: Priestly reference, haven't I given the name in the question? Or are you asking after something different? Also, your explanation implies that the class of quadra(i)variate distributions is quite broad, ie one can have a parameter for location, scale, asymmetry, and fat-tails. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: I meant 'the title of the work'. Sorry to be unclear. You seem to have misinterpreted the meaning of the term; it doesn't mean a distribution with four parameters, but one with four variables. I will clarify in my answer.

Comment: @Glen_b Oh! So it is just any joint distribution that is defined over 4 random variables? Well that is a lot simpler than I was imagining :-)  Also, the Priestly reference in the question is a textbook, not a journal article, so what I have provided is the title. [Here](http://books.google.com.au/books/about/Spectral_analysis_and_time_series.html?id=olYZAQAAIAAJ) is the google book reference. Thanks again. I'll tick and upvote forthcoming answer.

Comment: Yes, from the couple of lines Google books will show me, that's exactly what is being discussed on p 325 - a 'well known' result on joint distributions defined over four random variables. (It won't show me the result though)

Comment: Minute comment: Priestley not Priestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd interpret it to be a distribution on 4 variables - the next in the series univariate, bivariate, trivariate, ....

It's a multivariate random variable with four components.

However, the word is more often spelled quadrivariate, which might explain why you had trouble finding it.

To clarify; consider a gamma random variable $X\sim\text{gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$. That's univariate random variable; we say that the distribution of $X$ is a univariate distribution.

Now consider independent Poisson random variates $Z\sim\text{Pois}(\zeta)$, $X_1\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda_1)$ and $X_2\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda_2)$, and let $Y_1=X_1+Z$ and $Y_2=X_2+Z$. Then the distribution of $\left(\begin{array}{c}Y_1\\Y_2\end{array}\right)$ is an example of a bivariate Poisson distribution (in this case, one which has a correlation between its two components). Correspondingly $(Z,X_1,Y_2)'$ would be trivariate.

Now consider four independent normally distributed random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$, and $X_4$, with mean vector $\mu=(\mu_1,\mu_1,\mu_1,\mu_0)'$ and variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma=\sigma^2I$.

Then $\bf{X}$ $=(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)'$ is an example of a quadrivariate random variable.

So if for each observational unit I record four quantities, the observation on that unit is quadrivariate. The distribution of that quadrivariate random variable is a quadrivariate distribution.